# Loop en triggers en mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Que tal compañeros tengo un trigger en mysql que necesito que me actualice varios registros hasta el momento lo tengo así pero no funciona,podrían darme una mano y decirme en que estoy mal o que hacer para que funcione?

La idea es verificar primero si la consulta tiene resultados si es así a los resultados que me arroja actualizar ciertos campos.
gracias,saludos

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS historico;
CREATE TRIGGER historico_individivual AFTER INSERT ON historico_transferencia for each row

Begin

set @contador=    (Select count(e.datamatrixI) from  etiquetas_individuales e where e.datamatrixM =NEW.datamatrix);
set @individuales=(Select e.datamatrixI from  etiquetas_individuales e where e.datamatrixM =NEW.datamatrix);


while @contador>0
begin
UPDATE inventario SET Ubicacion=New.fk_id_ubicacion, Bin=NEW.fk_id_bin where Datamatrix = @individuales;
end

END;; 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: El drop inicial está borrando otra cosa diferente llamada `historico`, tu trigger se llama `historico_individivual`, no?

Comment: si, por eso no me preocupo tanto siempre al final lo reviso aun asi, gracias por la observacion

Comment: Cuando uno corre eso en producción y borra lo que no es, aprende que eso es para preocuparse **al comienzo**. ;)

Comment: Lo tengo en ambiente de pruebas, por eso no hay tanto problema, como te comento siempre antes de subirlo a server lo reviso para no borrar lo que no es en producción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea del trigger se entiende pero falta entender que estás obteniendo el conteo de filas en `@contador`. No recibes 1,2,3,4,5... sino que recibes un único número, por ejemplo 10.

Entonces, cuando haces

```
while @contador>0
begin
UPDATE inventario SET Ubicacion=New.fk_id_ubicacion, Bin=NEW.fk_id_bin where Datamatrix = @individuales;
end
```

Pasa que `@contador` nunca cambia, sigue siendo > 0 y pues... el while evalúa la condición de ejecución como verdadera y vuelve a hacer el UPDATE, una. vez. más.

Creo que lo que necesitas es un IF y no un while :)

El resultado de la consulta que alimenta `@contador` mira si hay datos. Cuando hay datos, la variable es > 0. Eso primero

Ahora, cuando tú corres un UPDATE, actualizas **TODOS** los campos de la tabla (inventario) a los que les caen las condiciones en el WHERE

Que, de hecho, ese WHERE te va a dar error cuando ese select de `@individuales` traiga más de un dato porque estarás usando `=` para comparar el valor `Datamatrix` de cada registro en `inventario` con una columna (y truena). Creería que necesitas un IN.

Es importante entender qué trae cada consulta para validar correctamente.

Sospecho que tu trigger debería verse más o menos así:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS historico_individivual;;
CREATE TRIGGER historico_individivual AFTER INSERT ON historico_transferencia 
for each row

BEGIN
    set @contador = (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(e.datamatrixI) 
        FROM etiquetas_individuales e 
        WHERE e.datamatrixM = NEW.datamatrix
    );

    IF @contador > 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE inventario 
            SET 
            Ubicacion = New.fk_id_ubicacion, 
            Bin = NEW.fk_id_bin 
            WHERE Datamatrix IN (
                SELECT e.datamatrixI 
                FROM etiquetas_individuales e 
                WHERE e.datamatrixM = NEW.datamatrix
            );
        END;
END;; 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tal vez, la idea es que solo haga el update si hay resultados de la consulta.
Aqui lo que no entiendo es como hacer para que actualice cada resultado que sale del @individuales

Comment: Respuesta actualizada. Es importante entender qué trae cada consulta y por qué la iteración que estás pensando no tiene mucho sentido en T-SQL

Comment: Gracias, con los cambios que tu hiciste funcionó